# Matlab GPU use with functions that take arguments of different dimensions

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

I am trying to use parallel computing with GPU in Matlab, and I would like to apply a function to a large array (to avoid the use of a for loop, which is quite slow). I have read Matlab's documentation, and I can use arrayfun, but only if I want to do elementwise operations. Maybe I am confused, but I would appreciate if someone can help me to use it. As an example of what I want to do, imagine that I would like to perform the following operation,

$X_t = B Z_t + Q\varepsilon_t$

where $X_t$ is 2x1, $B$ is 2x5, and $Z_t$ is 5x1, with $Q$ 2x2. I define a function,

```
function X = propose(Z,B,Q)
X=Z*B+Q*rand(2,1);
end
```

Now, suppose that I have an array $Z_p$ which is 5x1000. To each of the 1000 columns I would like to apply the previous function, for given matrices $B$ and $Q$, to get an array $X_p$ which is 2x1000.

Given the documentation for `arrayfun` I can not do this,

```
X=arrayfun(@propose,Zp,B,Q)
```

So, is there any possibility to do it?

Thanks!

**PS**: Yes, I know that in this simple example I can just do the multiplication without a for loop, but the application I have in mind is more complicated and I cannot do it. I just put this example as an illustration.

Comment: So you want to multiply and add 4 matrices in the GPU? why do you need arrayfun?

Comment: No, no, the problem I have is much more complicated, and it requires a long and slow loop. But the structure of what I would like to do is similar to this very simple problem I posted

Comment: The thing is, GPU computing is amazing, but doesnt work for everything! you can not paralelize any task, thus there is no generic solution to a GPU  problem. Ig everything would be paralelizable, then we wouldn't have CPUs anymore! My point: unlesh you show (or know) that your task is paralelizable, then you just cant!

Comment: Thanks, Ander. Yes, I know for sure that the task is parallelizable (it is a simulation process, in which each of the simulations is independent of the other one, but inside each simulation there are some algebraic operations). I could do it with parfor loops, but I would like to use the power of the GPU...

Comment: Each of the algorithms that can be paralelizable is paralelizable in a very specific way. Unless you show the task, its imposible for us to help.

Comment: Mmmm, explaining it here might be a daunting task... But I know that if I could make this little example work, I can make my application work, since the structure is the same. To sum up, I just need to apply to each column of a matrix a function. Each column is totally independent, and the function that I apply is just a bunch of linear algebra...